# autoload custom keyboard mapping when usb plugged in

Tags: keyboard, usb, registry, driver, autohotkey

I know how to use autohotkey and change the registry to remap keys to different keys and functions.  But, how would I go about making these new mappings automatically run right when the keyboard is plugged in?  I want to buy these keyboards and resell them, and I don't want the user to have to run a script.

I'm hoping this doesn't involve developing a new driver.

Comment: Try something with http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8231-usb-device-connecteddisconnected-notification/page-2